# python scraping return 403

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-403

i have built a python script that scrapes some info from it.indeed.com and retrieves some information

I've been building it for the last couple of weeks, no problems

Today as I went back to it, didn't work; traced my way back to the beginning where i tested the requests response and i'm receiving `403`, while it is still accessible from every browser without problems

Tested on many other websites and get `200` except indeed.com and indeed.it

Tried changing my IP and still get the same result.

I didn't see any ban on scraping or anything.

What should i do? Is it a block on their part or am i missing something?

=========== edit ======

Adding some context:
changed the user agent with a more recent one and seems to work in the homepage

```
agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/5.3.2679.70.'}
x = requests.get("http://www.indeed.com", headers=agent)

print(x.status_code)
>>> 200
```

returns 200
but as soon as i do the same with the url my code uses, it still gives me 403

```
r = requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=it+support&l=miami&start=0&pp=gQAeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4OOm7wAvAQEBCAHr6EsjGDwNhFuHbHnTkwsODfPz7YMYVlIdi-kkk8O0rJkYvGplLcCOkW4AAA", headers=agent)

print(r.status_code)
>>> 403
```

I'm out of knowledge on what to do

Comment: Hi try to add some headers to your request maybe it can solve the problem cause you still have access to website via browser

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention, I already had headers and user agent and changed a bit, but it still isn't working.  Worked fine 2 days ago

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It work for me i got both 200 status code look the answer

Answer (score 1):

**As You can see i got the status code 200 for both requests**

**Try it in shell**

**Code :**

```
>>> import requests
>>> agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/5.3.2679.70.'}
>>> x = requests.get("http://www.indeed.com", headers=agent)
>>> print(x.status_code)
200
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=it+support&l=miami&start=0&pp=gQAeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4OOm7wAvAQEBCAHr6EsjGDwNhFuHbHnTkwsODfPz7YMYVlIdi-kkk8O0rJkYvGplLcCOkW4AAA", headers=agent)
>>> print(r.status_code)
200
>>>
```

**Take Two**

**CODE :**

It Just work fine how many times you try **I think they blocked your ip from multiple requests**

```
python                                                                                                                                                                
Python 3.10.5                                                                                           
>>> import requests                                                                                                                                                       
>>> agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/5.3.2679.70.'}            
>>> x = requests.get("http://www.indeed.com", headers=agent)                                                                                                              
>>> print(x.status_code)                                                                                                                                                  
200                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=it+support&l=miami&start=0&pp=gQAeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4OOm7wAvAQEBCAHr6EsjGDwNhFuHbHnTkwsODfPz7YMYVlIdi-kkk8O0rJkYvGplLcCOkW4AAA", headers=agent)                                                                                                                                                   
>>> print(r.status_code)                                                                                                                                                  
200                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> print(r.status_code)                                                                                                                                                  
200                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> print(r.status_code)                                                                                                                                                  
200
>>> import requests
>>> agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/5.3.2679.70.'}
>>> x = requests.get("http://www.indeed.com", headers=agent)
>>> print(x.status_code)
200
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=it+support&l=miami&start=0&pp=gQAeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4OOm7wAvAQEBCAHr6EsjGDwNhFuHbHnTkwsODfPz7YMYVlIdi-kkk8O0rJkYvGplLcCOkW4AAA", headers=agent)
>>> print(r.status_code)
200
>>> import requests
>>> agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/5.3.2679.70.'}
>>> x = requests.get("http://www.indeed.com", headers=agent)
>>> print(x.status_code)
200
>>> r = requests.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=it+support&l=miami&start=0&pp=gQAeAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4OOm7wAvAQEBCAHr6EsjGDwNhFuHbHnTkwsODfPz7YMYVlIdi-kkk8O0rJkYvGplLcCOkW4AAA", headers=agent)
>>> print(r.status_code)
200
>>>
```

Comment: tried the same as you did in shell, and i still receive 200 for the first, and 403 for the second

how can this be a problem on my side?

Comment: Updated the answer check, the problem is from your side!

Comment: I thought about being blocked, but I didn't flood the servers with requests...i mean...it was just testing, and kinda spread out between days
I tried using a VPN but still the same, now i was thinking as a last resort about trying it on a VPS but it wouldn't help me really... i'd be screwed.

Also...I didn't find any disclaimer about this not being allowed

Also, the VPN gets me 403 on every request

Comment: I think i got it to work, by switching from https:// to http://, but I don't really understand why would that happen, and why it is limited on my end
Tried to run it through a vpn connection to a friend of mine in another city, still got the same result, but then i tried in a virtual machine on Linode and it worked

On my end I only got it to work by only using http

I lack the knowledge to understand what happened, but still...

Comment: Good :) Debug your network